# Android Manifest file

Tags: android

what is the use of xmlns:android ? could you explain little bit more? Thanks in advance

*Note :
xmlns:android
Defines the Android namespace. This attribute should always be set to "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android".*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the namespace for the XML.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace) wraps it up nicely:

> XML namespaces are used for providing
>   uniquely named elements and attributes
>   in an XML document. They are defined
>   in Namespaces in XML, a W3C 
>   recommendation. An XML instance may
>   contain element or attribute names
>   from more than one XML vocabulary. If
>   each vocabulary is given a namespace
>   then the ambiguity between identically
>   named elements or attributes can be
>   resolved.

Basically, it's used to identify the android specific tags and to avoid mix-up with other elements that have the same name but are not related with android.